# How to access list value inside dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary as

```
local={'obj1' : p }
```

where p is object of some other class name with structure

```
class name:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    time = 0
    PCH = []
    FCC_Queue = []
```

i have stored value using object of class **name** and now i want to check  value present inside PCH and FCC_Queue. suppose i wanted to check 10 is present inside PCH list or not what should i have to write as condition of if statement?

Answer (score 7):

> i wanted to check 10 is present inside PCH list

```
if 10 in local["obj1"].PCH:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class name:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    time = 0
    PCH = []
    FCC_Queue = []


p = name()
local = {}
local['obj1'] = p

((1 in local['obj1'].PCH) | (1 in local['obj1'].FCC_Queue))
False

local['obj1'].PCH.append(1)
((1 in local['obj1'].PCH) | (1 in local['obj1'].FCC_Queue))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local={'obj1' : p }
if 10 in local["obj1"].PCH:
    # do something
```

This works because after the look up for `PCH` in `p` fails, the search moves to `p.__class__`, which is `name` and it has `PCH`. Bdw, if that is all there is to `name`, better use a `namedtuple` instead of a `class`. The latter is bulkier and slower.

Comment: actuallu local={} is a global dictionary hence i am using concept of struct type class to keep records

Comment: @OmPrakashKumar didn't know that. apologies.